# Flex sticky footer overlaps flex siblings on window resize (height shrink)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very simple flexbox structure with a header, main and footer child elements, where the footer is ending item and plays the role as a sticky footer to stay on the bottom of the page on long pages. But whenever the window is shrunk (height), the footer overlaps all the content  (other siblings) like it would have a fixed position property.

I would like it to have a default behavior and be equal to others which are hidden when site height is too small for current last item to be shown.

My structure:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="alternate_header"></div>
  <div id="header">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">body</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {

  margin: 0;
  height:100vh;

}

#main {

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  min-height:0;

}

#main > div {

  width: 100%;

}

#alternate_header {

  display; none;

}

#header {

  background-color:red;
  height:5rem;
  line-height:5rem;
  align-self:flex-start;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

}

#header > div {

  flex:1;
}

#content {

  flex:1;
  background-color:#dcdcdc;
  min-height:0;

}

#footer {

  align-self:flex-end;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 4rem;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/23uypjtg/1/)

Comment: Why do you set a fixed height on `html`, `body` & `#main`?

Comment: Yes, figured it out. Fixed height on mentioned elements cause this. It should all be `min-height`. Add an answer to be accepted for others not to make the same mistake.

Comment: Good job for working it out. I've added an answer with a bit more explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by setting a fixed height on your containers: `html`, `body` and `#main`. This means that the height of your flexbox container will always be exactly `100vh`: the height of the viewport.

Your `#footer` element has `align-self: flex-end`. This means that it will align itself to the end of your flex container: the bottom of the page.

You can have the same effect of ensuring that the page covers the whole screen, while allowing the page to grow and the footer to move with it, by replacing:

```
 height: 100vh;
```

with:

```
 max-height: 100vh;
```

in `html`, `body` & `#main`.

In addition, the header and footer will naturally align to the start and end as that's where they are in the DOM. Feel free to remove the `align-self` rules.